# jQuery plugin destroy function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I put together this plugin from reading various articles and tutorials on building plugins for jquery. It all works very well except that I can't remove/unbind/destroy the plugin on certain elements. I've tried a couple of methods but I can't get it to work.

I basically want to be able to call something like this on an element.

```
$('element').tip('destroy');
```

Here is my plugin.

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
"use strict";

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var mobileDevice = false;
var tabletDevice = false;
var desktopDevice = false;
var mobile = '';
var tablet = '';
var desktop = '';

$.fn.extend({
    tip: function (options) {

        var defaults = {
            mobile: 620,
            tablet: 1024,
            desktop: 1333,
            tipDelay: 300,
            tipDuration: 300
        }

        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {


        });
    }
});
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to include your entire plugin code in the question? It might be advisable to trim it down to just the parts that matter or remove it entirely.

Comment: Not sure which part to exclude but here you go.

Comment: Looks good to me, but I'm no jquery expert. [This help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) probably explains what I'm getting at better than I can.